# How to send UTF-8 email?

Tags: php, email, utf-8

When I send out the email, the email does not show characters other than english.
It does show like below:

> ä½™ç”Ÿä»ä»

May know actually what cause this?
Even I tried to added Content-type and charset in the script, it still show the same.

I used `Mail::Factory("mail");`

Comment: What do you use? native `mail()` or `Zend_Mail` or `PHPMailer`? Need some code of the Factory method!

Comment: You have to additionally take care of the destination email clients. Even if you get it managed to view the email correctly in your email client does not mean your customer will see the mail correct to. In the end I always build html-emails with utf-8 charset header. This way most email-clients display the content correctly.

Comment: @FlyBy: yea, that exactly what I want to do, display the content with utf-8 charset, but I still cannot see the email correctly.

Comment: Content-Type and charset are precisely what you need in order to make this work, but you need to give us more information.  Can you show us the code. and/or the resulting message's source?  Are you sure your data is correctly utf8 encoded?

Comment: here is my example code:
    `$mail = Mail::factory("mail");`
    `$to = "me@abc.com";`
    `$body = "好信";`
    `$headers = array("Content-type =>"text/plain: charset=\"UTF-8","From" => "abc@abc.com","To" => "me@abc.com","Subject" => "Test Send Chinese mail-好信");`
    `$mail->send($to, $headers, $body);`
    

Is this correct? It does not show what I expect. It should display out chinese word in body,header or even subject.

Comment: @tripleee: there is one line to get the data from.
eg: `$objects['test']['data']`
and before all of these, there is one line here:
`$objects = array_map('unserialize', array_map('htmlspecialchars_decode', HTTP::getParam('objects', array())));`

Comment: No-one can answer your question because the mail component you're using is still unknown albeit even asked for.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP or Mail::factory but the documentation implies that you need to use Mail_MIME if you want to send MIME, which most definitely you want to in order for this to work.  It would be nice if Mail::factory knew that it needs to encapsulate and encode stuff which isn't 7-bit, but it doesn't, does it?

Comment: @hakre: I used PEAR. so does this can encode content in email? I tried set content to be utf-8 like code above but it failed.

Comment: Please make clear in your question that you're using PEAR Mail.

Answer (score 127):

You can add header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" to your message body.

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

If you use native `mail()` function $headers array will be the 4th parameter 
`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`

If you user PEAR Mail::factory() code will be:

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: here is my code
    $mail = Mail::factory("mail");
    $to = "me@abc.com";
    $body = "好信";
    $headers = array("Content-type =>"text/plain: charset=\"UTF-8","From" => "abc@abc.com","To" => "me@abc.com","Subject" => "Test Send Chinese mail-好信");
    $mail->send($to, $headers, $body)
    

Is this correct? It does not show what I expect. It should display out chinese word in body,header or even subject.

Comment: UTF-8 requires 8 bits. Most email tools still use: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit. The results will be dependent on the tools your content goes through but try adding an entry to the headers array of Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: Which email tools stil use 7-bit transfer encoding ?

Comment: The 4th parameter to php `mail()` is a string, not an array!!

Comment: Be sure to write `charset=UTF-8` without quotes around `UTF-8`!

Comment: Only use `text/html` if you're sending an email in HTML format.  For plain text emails, you want `text/plain`.

Comment: I think you mean "to your message" rather than "to your message body".

Answer (score 37):

I'm using rather specified charset (ISO-8859-2) because not every mail system (for example: http://10minutemail.com) can read UTF-8 mails. If you need this:

```
function utf8_to_latin2($str)
{
    return iconv ( 'utf-8', 'ISO-8859-2' , $str );
}
function my_mail($to,$s,$text,$form, $reply)
    {
        mail($to,utf8_to_latin2($s),utf8_to_latin2($text),
        "From: $form\r\n".
        "Reply-To: $reply\r\n".
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
    }
```

I have made another mailer function, because apple device could not read well the previous version.

```
function utf8mail($to,$s,$body,$from_name="x",$from_a = "info@x.com", $reply="info@x.com")
{
    $s= "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($s)."?=";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($from_name)."?= <".$from_a.">\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers.= "Reply-To: $reply\r\n";  
    $headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    mail($to, $s, $body, $headers);
}
```

Comment: And what if you're trying to send content which cannot be represented in ISO-8859-2?!

Comment: `$headers.= "From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($from_name)."?= <".$from_a.">\r\n";` this line solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Consider quoted printable encoding for readability in plain text mailers, it's just as simple: `'=?utf-8?Q?' . quoted_printable_encode($string) . '?='`

Comment: @Julia Thanks, my too.

Comment: what about cc and bcc?

Comment: For those reading this answer and wondering what the `=?utf-8?b?=` is about, see https://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/ for the details.

Answer (score 3):

If not `HTML`, then `UTF-8` is not recommended. `koi8-r` and `windows-1251` only without problems. So use html mail.

```
$headers['Content-Type']='text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$body='<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>ESP Notufy - ESP Сообщения</title></head><body>'.$text.'</body></html>';


$mail_object=& Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));
$mail_object->send($recipents, $headers, $body);
}
```