# Drupal to Pear Mail UTF-8 encoding failure

Tags: drupal, utf-8, pear

I have a perfectly functioning Drupal site developed for me by Venture Web.

My problem is that I dont have php mail() available on my server but have the Pear mail utility instead.  I am currently linking out of Drupal to a mail utility I developed myself in PHP that calls the Pear mail functions.

It works fine with the exception of the fact that there seems to be an issue with the UTF-8 encoding.  It is most obvious where French language characters are involved.

For example if I try to mail the phrase:

Test pour les caractères spéciaux.  À, ç, ê, ù

When I display the contents of the variable into which I am capturing the message, $message, I get exactly what you see above.

But when the email is delivered I get:

Test pour les caractÃ¨res spÃ©ciaux. Â Ã€, Ã§, Ãª, Ã¹

Here is the pertinent PHP code:

```
    $hdrs = array(
    'From'      => $email,
    'To'        => $tomail,
    'Cc'        => not included for security reasons,
    'Subject'   => $subjectline,
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'quoted-printable'
                       );
    $recipients=$tomail.', inquiries@barkbusters.ca';
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    //do not ever try to call these lines in reverse order
    $body = $mime->get(array('text_charset' => 'utf-8'));
    $hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

    $params["host"] = 'smtp.barkbusters.ca';
    $params["port"] = "26";
    $params["auth"] = true;
    $params["username"] = not included for security reasons;
    $params["password"] = not included for security reasons;

    $mail =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
    $mail->send($recipients, $hdrs, $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not too sure about your pear mail utility, but normal php headers for utf-8 look like this

`$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Here is some helpful information..
[How to send UTF-8 email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email-php)