# contact form not working well with non English characters

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have the following contact form:

(HTML with PHP)

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">

    <p>
      <label>Namn</label>
      <input name="name" placeholder="Skriv här">

      <label>Epost adress</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Skriv här">

      <label>Meddelande</label>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Skriv här"></textarea>

      <label>Hur mycket är 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
  <input name="human" placeholder="Skriv här">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>



    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Från: Forall.se'; 
    $to = 'info@forall.se'; 
    $subject = 'Ny meddelande';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Ditt meddelande har skickats!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Någonting gick fel. Var vänlig och försök igen!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>Du har gett fel svar på Anti-Spam frågan!</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Du behöver att fylla alla fält i formuläret!</p>';
    }
}

?>

</form>
```

Everything is woring as it should, except non English characters like ã, õ, ä, å, ö, ç and so on. This shouldn't be a problem if it wasn't a swedish website.

Here's a sample of the last e-mail I received:

"Jag hoppas du har fÃ¶rstÃ¥else fÃ¶r detta och att du hittar nÃ¥gon annan marknadsfÃ¶rare!
Jag Ã¥terkommer nÃ¤r och om jag startar upp min firma, just nu Ã¤r det lite osÃ¤kert hur det blir med dettas"

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email

Comment: So, if I understood right, I have to just add "$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");" and not to all my variables, right? Because the labels are also having the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add headers

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Från: Forall.se'; 
    $to = 'info@forall.se'; 
    $subject = 'Ny meddelande';
    $human = $_POST['human'];


    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "From: $from <$email> ". PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 ". PHP_EOL;

   $name = str_replace( '[at]','@', $name);
   $message = str_replace( '[at]','@', $message);

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
            echo '<p>Ditt meddelande har skickats!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Någonting gick fel. Var vänlig och försök igen!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>Du har gett fel svar på Anti-Spam frågan!</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Du behöver att fylla alla fält i formuläret!</p>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Really appreciated for this answer!!! There was an "if" but I went around it. The variable "$from" wasn't being affected by this... So, not to be stuck for longer time I took off the word "Från" and the problem did not exist any longer. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

PHP [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function 4th parameter isn't exclusive to send a from value. Acording with PHP's manual:

*-This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).*

Including charset which will encode the text of the message. In your case, as the comments says, you'll have to use **UTF-8**.

So, your code would be like this:

```
$header = "From: somebody@example.com\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'info@forall.se'; 
$subject = 'Ny meddelande';


mail ($to, $subject, $body, $header)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Luigi. Unfortunately it didn't work. I already marked the correct answer. Trully thankful for your time!