# PHP array with words separated by commas

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm using an array to send form mail. The array includes the subject of each field option in the form.

```
array("0",""),
array("1","Subject 1a, Text","Subject 1b","Subject 1c"),
array("2","Subject 2a","Subject 2b","Subject 2c")
```

When the form is delivered to the client, the subject line says "Form: Subject xx".

```
$subject = "Form: ".$value[1];
```

However, if the subject contains a comma as it does in the first example (i.e. "Subject 1a, Text") the form is delivered with only **Form: Subject 1a** in the subject field.

It doesn't send the full subject line with the comma and the words after it (i.e. **Form: Subject 1a, Text**).

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Comment: Where does `$value` come from?

Comment: More info is needed. How are you passing `$subject` into a mailing utility, and how are you generating `$value`?

Comment: You can use fputcsv() to change the escape character to a **"**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");

$subject = "Testmail — Special Characters";
$msg = "Hi there,\n\nthis isn’t something easy.\n\nI haven’t thought that it’s that complicated!";

mail(utf8_decode($to), utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($msg), utf8_decode($from)."\nContent-    Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n");?>
```

Do the encoding/decoding properly.
Referred from [php mail special characters utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708097/php-mail-special-characters-utf8)

Comment: I don't believe this is related to the issue at hand - the characters come out fine in the email