# Problems using Acute in phpmailer subject

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Codes:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSendmail();
$mail->setFrom('info@rene.org', 'Rene');
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = 'Confirmación';
```

Ive used the own "ó", and the subject will appear as: ConfirmaciÃ³n
in my email account. I've also tried:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSendmail();
$mail->setFrom('info@rene.org', 'Rene');
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = 'Confirmaci&oacute;n';
```

And it appear like: Confirmaci & o a c u t e ;n.
How can i solve this guys. It needs to appear on emails inboxes like: Confirmación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be encountering your first character encoding bug. Congratulations! You've taken your first step into a world of crippling legacy and enormous mistakes that shall be preserved for all of time. Let's dive right in.

> Ive used the own "ó" and the subject will appear as: ConfirmaciÃ³n in my email account.

Before I begin explaining why this happened, I want to make something clear: you had *every reason* to believe this would work. In a perfect world, it would have. Your tools have failed you.

When you type `'ó'` in your PHP source, you're not actually telling PHP what you think you are. What you want to say is, "Give me a string containing the codepoint U+00F3 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE". PHP doesn't speak Unicode, though; its strings are actually byte vectors. What PHP heard is "Give me the byte vector < C3 B3 >", and so it does. By the time the message hits your screen, *something* has decided those bytes must be characters encoded according to Microsoft Codepage 1252:

```
$ echo 'ó' | iconv -f cp1252
Ã³
```

This is probably PHPMailer behavior, but the documentation for `PHPMailer::$Subject` only says

> The Subject of the message.

so that's not exactly a big help.

---

Okay, I've dug around on the PHPMailer bug tracker a bit, and I found [this conversation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/133). There's a lot of stuff there that doesn't apply to this situation, but I *did* manage to learn that the `PHPMailer::$CharSet` property also applies to the headers. (Documentation: "The character set of the message.") So it appears the correct fix for your situation is to add the line

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

to the bottom of your first script.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post and try the options there, setting the encoding should solve it.

[php mail special characters utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708097/php-mail-special-characters-utf8)

Comment: Please don't do this. `utf8_decode` is misnamed; it should be called `utf8_to_iso_8859_1`, because that's the conversion it actually does. There's no reason to use it when actual UTF-8 support is available.