# php form with accents characters issue

Tags: php, forms, email, character, encode

I have a registration form and if I use accent characters on the name input, the email doesn't come to my email client. Without accents it is ok.
If I type "ROkkenbauer Pal" - and submit I get the mail.
If I type "Rokkenbáúer Pál" - and submit I do not get the email.

Thank you!!!

```
      <?php 
      $action = $_REQUEST['action']; 
      if ($action == "") { 
         /* display the contact form */ 
          ?> 
          <form  action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">    
          <input id="nev" name="name" type="text" value="" size="100" placeholder="NÉV" maxlength="100"/>   
          <input id="kuld" type="submit" value="JÖVÖK"/> 
          </form> 
          <?php 
          } else { 
             /* send the submitted data */
             $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 

             if ($name == "") { 
                echo "XXXX"; 
             } else {         
                $from = "$name"; 
                $subject = "some subj"; 
                mail("myemail@myemail.com", $name, $from); 
                echo "THX"; 
             } 
          }   
      ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708097/php-mail-special-characters-utf8

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Using accents should not cause any issues when you have UTF-8 as standard. This explains a lot http://kunststube.net/encoding/