# specials characters when sending mail via Php

Tags: php, email, special-characters

I've got this php code that send an email with some texts and special characters :

```
// send email
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$mail_user= "myMail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message d'alerte" ;

$message = utf8_encode("Une personne est en danger !\r\n \r\n <br> Nom :$nom  <br> Prénom : $prenom <br>   Numéro de téléphone : $phone\r\n   <br> Type de bateau : $boat\r\n Téléphone du proche : $phoneFriend <br> ");

mail($mail_user, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Problem**

The user receive this email :

```
Une personne est en danger ! 
Nom :amir 
PrÃ©nom : Khalida 
NumÃ©ro de tÃ©lÃ©phone : 95626    
CoordonnÃ©es :
TÃ©lÃ©phone du proche
```

As you can see, every character with accents are not supported.. How can I do to change "Ã©" by "é" when sending the email ?

Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mail special characters utf8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708097/php-mail-special-characters-utf8)

Comment: `utf8_encode - Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8` you aren't sending `iso-8859-1`

Answer (score 1):

Change your charset:

```
$headers .= "From: $from \r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n';
```