# php mail not taking client valid email address

Tags: php, email

I am using simple php mail. It's working perfectly fine but when I add abc@gmail.com to mail body it's just not working but when I replace abc@gmail.com with abc(a)gmail(dot)com, it's working perfectly fine and coming in email. What exactly is the problem here ? Is it some server issue ?
Code:

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$partnername = $_POST['partnername'];
$placename = $_POST['placename'];
$datepicker = $_POST['datepicker'];
$coverage = $_POST['coverage'];
$clientmail =$_POST['email_client'];
$email_message = "Form details below.<br>";
$email_message .= "Full Name: ".$fullname."<br>";
$email_message .= "Parter Name: ".$partnername."<br>";
$email_message .= "Found Via: ".$placename."<br>";
$email_message .= "Date: ".$datepicker."<br>";
$email_message .= "Coverage: ".$coverage."<br>";
$email_message .= "Client Email: ".$clientmail;
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
     $msg = 'YOUR MESSAGE HAS BEEN SENT. THANKS!';
     $type = ' success';
     unset($_POST);
} else {
     $msg = 'Validation error. Check the boxes and send back.';
     $type = ' error';
}
```

Any help/suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or the mail just isn't arriving? It sounds like a spam filter at Gmail doesn't like messages that have the recipient's email in the body.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19708243/4965214

Comment: @Barmar, I ma not getting error. In fact success message is posted.

Comment: So code crashes when you try to use `$clientmail = 'abc@gmail.com'`, right?

Comment: @wormi4ok ... goes to success message (if clause) but no mail is coming.

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder? Have you checked the mail server logs to see if the mail is being sent?

Comment: @Barmar it's not in spam folder ... about server logs need to ask the client.

Comment: are you trying this on localhost or on server?

Comment: @NishantNair ... it's not loca but live server(binero server)