# Special characters in html/php form - UTF8 not working

Tags: php, html, forms, character

This form accepts special characters (é,à,ç,è,...) in every place EXCEPT "naam" and "voornaam", wich means Name and First Name.

When people with a special character in their name would fill in the fields I would not recieve the message, wich is very weird since it works in every field except "naam" and "voornaam".

Any help please?

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

            $onderwerp = "Iemand gebruikte het contactformulier"; 

            $emailadres = ( trim($_POST['email']) == "" ) ? 'contact@xxx.be' : $_POST['email']; // E-mailadres van de afzender
            $naar = 'xxx@outlook.be'; // E-mailadres van de ontvanger

            $afzendernaam = explode('@',$emailadres);
            $afzendernaam = $_POST['naam'] . ' ' . $_POST['voornaam'];

            $header = "From: ".$afzendernaam." <".$emailadres.">\r\n"; 
            $header .= "Reply-To: ".$emailadres." \r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            $header .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
            $header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n";
            $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP / ".phpversion()."\r\n";


            $mail = 'Naam: '.$_POST['naam'].'
                    Voornaam: '.$_POST['voornaam'].'
                    Adres: '.$_POST['straat'].'
                    Postcode: '.$_POST['postcode'].'
                    Telefoon: '.$_POST['telefoon'].'
                    E-mail: '.$_POST['email'].'
                    Bericht: '.$_POST['bericht'].'';

            mail($naar, $onderwerp, $mail,$header);
            echo "Het formulier is succesvol verzonden, u kan nu verder gaan op de website.";

        }
        else
        {
?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <p class="underline">Of via ons online contactformulier:</p>
    <br>
    <label>Uw naam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="naam">
    <br>
    <label>Uw voornaam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="voornaam">
    <br>
    <label>Uw straat en huisnummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="straat">
    <br>
    <label>Uw postcode:</label>
    <input type="number" name="postcode">
    <br>
    <label>Uw telefoonnummer:</label>
    <input type="number" name="telefoon">
    <br>
    <label>Uw e-mailadres:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <br>
    <label>Uw bericht:</label>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="25" name="bericht"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden" class="submit">
  </form>
</div>
<?php

        }
?>
```

Comment: have you used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-UTF-8"> in your html.

Comment: @ user3598594 Yes, I have also used it there.

Comment: Please read this it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email