# How to send email using PHP to other email service

Tags: php, email, yahoo

I have a problem sending email from PHP to yahoo email when characters are in Persian. 
The code is:

```
$msg = "some persian words";
$from = "my_email@my_server.com";
$headers = "From: $from\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "BCC: $to".PHP_EOL;
$message =  '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>Message</title></head>
<body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
'.htmlspecialchars_decode($msg).'
<div style="margin-top:5px">Please do not reply to this email.</div>
</div></body></html>';
```

I don't have problem the text content sending to Gmail but in Yahoo mail the encoding Persian characters does not work and it is like this:

ØªÙ†Ø§Ø³Ù„Ø¨Ø± Ù†Ù…ØªØ§Ø±Ø¨Ù…Ù†Øª

Comment: use a UTF-8 character set instead of charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: The header has charset=iso-8859-1\n and for the body it is UTF-8. Does both should be UTF-8?

Comment: I tend to think so, yes. Try it out `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";` as per this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/7266935/

Comment: so, success? fail? still working on it? ;-)

Comment: I changed the header to UTF-8 but the massage does not send to yahoo mail. Gmail is receiving the email but not yahoo mail. Weird happening here. I just should note that it was okay couple of weeks ago. I am not sure if yahoo changed anything in their server.

Comment: *Hm....,* most bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Mail Mime](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)

this is an example from the Mail Mime repository in git https://github.com/pear/Mail_Mime/blob/master/scripts/phail.php

```
<?php
/**
* PHAIL - stands for PHP Mail
* @author Tomas V.V.Cox <cox@idecnet.com>
*/
require_once 'Mail.php';
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';
require_once 'Console/Getopt.php';
$argv = Console_Getopt::readPHPArgv();
$opts = Console_Getopt::getOpt($argv, 'f:c:s:t:a:b:');
if (PEAR::isError($opts)) {
    usage($opts->getMessage());
}
PEAR::setErrorHandling(PEAR_ERROR_DIE);
$mime = new Mail_mime;
foreach ($opts[0] as $opt) {
    $param = $opt[2];
    switch ($opt[0]) {
        case 'f':
            $headers['From'] = $param; break;
        case 'c':
            $headers['Cc'] = $param; break;
        case 's':
            $headers['Subject'] = $param; break;
        case 't':
            $to = $param; break;
        case 'a':
            $mime->addAttachment($param); break;
        case 'b':
            $isfile = @is_file($param) ? true : false;
            $mime->setTXTBody($param, $isfile); break;
    }
}
$mbody   = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$mail    = Mail::factory('mail');
$mail->send($to, $headers, $mbody);
function usage($error)
{
    die($error);
}
?>
```