# mail() doesn't send message body correctly, subject -- ok

Tags: php, email, webforms, character-encoding

script takes data from webform and sends it to mail client and crm. Data from webform is in cyrillic. 
What I can't figure out is why I do receive `$email_subject` as needed, `"Заголовок"`, and `$email_message` instead of `"Сообщение"` -- I get either `"Ð¡Ð¾Ð¾Ð±ÑÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ"` or `"=?utf-8?B?0KHQvtC+0LHRidC10L3QuNC1Cgo=?="` depending on encoding method.

`echo mb_detect_encoding($email_message);` shows that $email_message is utf-8.

```
$email_to = "mail@mail.zu";
$email_subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode("Заголовок")."?=";

//... here goes some code for taking data from webform, checking etc.

$email_message = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode("Сообщение")."?=";
//I have also tried $email_message = mb_convert_encoding("Сообщение", "utf-8","AUTO");

$headers = 'От: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Ответить: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: `try with (mb_convert_encoding("Сообщение", "utf-8")`, because its showing correct at my local.

Comment: As I have mentioned, //I have also tried $email_message = mb_convert_encoding("Сообщение", "utf-8","AUTO"); And w/o AUTO also..

Answer (score 1):

hi allow mail header to send utf-8 character-set add these line in your header

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

also refer you in [How to send UTF-8 email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email)

Comment: yes, I have it, forgot to copy: '$headers .= "\n".'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n".'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";'."\n".'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64';'

Answer (score 0):

this

```
   iconv ('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-5', $str);
```

helped. Although I have tried it before, it looks like I was wrong choosing inappropriate ISO-. What confused me is that with mail clients, like Outlook, Mail or webmails (like gmail) there were no problems, contrary to CRM.
Now everything's ok.