# How can I make my form send UTF-8 emails?

Tags: php, email, utf-8

My form:

```
    <form class="form" role="form"action="message.php" method="POST">   
        <input  type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <input  type="text" name="message" id="name">   
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" id="subject" value="New Message" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Senden" class="btn" />
    </form>
```

message.php

```
<?php
$recipient = "my_email@test.com";
$fmtMail= implode("", file("assets/email.htt"));
foreach($_POST as $key=> $val) {
$fmtResponse= str_replace("<$key>", $val, $fmtResponse);
$fmtMail= str_replace("<$key>", $val, $fmtMail);
$from = "FROM: Example <noreply@example.com>\r\n";
 }
mail($recipient, $_POST["subject"], $fmtMail, $from);
```

My Email form is working well, the only problem is: When someone fills out the form, I will get an email, that is not in UTF-8. So it is very difficult for me to read it. I know that I have to write somewhere `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"` but I do not know, where is the place I need to put it in my code.

Comment: The form has nothing to do with mail function. You must change php code. Look at utf8mail function in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7267426/789186