# Weird characters in e-mail content only on AOL accounts?

Tags: php, email, html-email

i get clients who complain about weird characters

> Â  Donation Receipt:
>    Â
>
> If donor provided extra information, here is the information:
>   Â

this only happens on AOL. Or at least, seems to only happen there.

this is the mail call.

```
  $headers .= "From: " . "Jewcer  <info@myapp.com>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . "info@myapp.com" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . "<{$fromEmail}>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . "{$fromEmail}" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  mail($to, $title, $content, $headers);
```

Any idea what might causing this problem? generally it works, just AOL and some other odd clients cause problems

Comment: Looks like you are putting UTF-8 character points in your ISO-8859-1 mail body.

Comment: Use a different character set => UTF-8 RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: well fair enough "RTM" but it doesn't really help. I found a solution here on stackoverflow, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that worked for me was this:

```
function utf8mail($to,$s,$body,$from_name="x",$from_a = "info@x.com", $reply="info@x.com")
{
    $s= "=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($s)."?=";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($from_name)."?= <".$from_a.">\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers.= "Reply-To: $reply\r\n";  
    $headers.= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    mail($to, $s, $body, $headers);
}
```

from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7267426/533426