# PDO send email using UTF-8

Tags: php, email, mysqli, pdo

In the following code I used the following line to add the encoding part:

`$mail->exec("set names utf8");`

However, the email was not sent correctly.

I have tried the following:

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
      $subject = "Konfirmo regjistrimin ZEROPULSE Team";
      $body = "<p>Përshendetje $emri, faleminderit per anetaresimin tuaj ne webfaqen <a href='http://www.flamurbeqiraj.com'>www.flamurbeqiraj.com</a>!</p>
      <p>Per te aktivizuar llogarine tuaj, ju lutem <a href='".DIR."administrator/aktivizo.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>klikoni ketu</a>.</p>
      <p>T'gjitha te mirat, ZP Team.</p>";

      $mail = new Mail();
      $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
      $mail->addAddress($to);
      $mail->subject($subject);
      $mail->exec("set names utf8");
      $mail->body($body);
      $mail->send();
```

How can I change the encoding UTF-8 part?

Comment: `$mail->exec("set names utf8");` - seriously ...? You're confusing mindless copy&paste with actually reading up on how stuff works here. (But you still gotte do that yourself, because you failed to inform us what `Mail` is supposed to be in the first place, because a native PHP class that ain't.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

Actually for pdo you have to do utf-8 charset in the connection:

```
new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8")
```

Comment: This is my PDO connection
`$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);` so it should be like this?:
`$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS.";charset=utf8");`

Comment: No, like this: `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME.";charset=utf8", DBUSER, DBPASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));`

Comment: same problem, dhe "ë" character is displaying as "Ã«" :/

Comment: Ah, i see, you need to specify the header in the mail.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email