# PHP Mail norwegian characters error

Tags: php, email, special-characters

I use PHP mail function to send some data from my database to Ø or æ, it gets replaced with some random characters.

Actual name: Kørsgaard
In mail: Kï¿½rsgaard

How do I fix this issue? I'm using mail() for sending the email.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @SujitAgarwal https://pastebin.com/LeK2MS2D

Comment: You must use UTF-8 in header of this emails for Norwegian. I guess your problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email

Comment: Take a look at code examples contributed at at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php . You need one fix for headers (`To:`,`From:`,`Subject:`, ...) and special 3 headers to declare encoding of email body.

Answer (score 0):

Emails are normaly send as html, just try handle it like any special character in html by looking up the character on: https://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Comment: The values comes from database. How do I replace those values that are coming dynamically.

Comment: There is a php function that does that for you: http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php