# PHP mail encoding issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

i found an issue with php mail sending. I need to encode the mail in UTF-8. The subject works fine, but the message is corrupted. This is my code

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $mail = $_POST['fmail'];
    $discord = $_POST['fdiscord'];
    $vek = $_POST['fage'];
    $q1 = $_POST['fq1'];
    $q2 = $_POST['fq2'];
    $q3 = $_POST['fq3'];
    $q4 = $_POST['fq4'];
    $q5 = $_POST['fq5'];

    $mailto = "nabor@cloud-mc.cz";
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From: ".$mail;
    $mailsub = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode("Nábor - ".$name) . '?=';
    $mailmsg =  '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode("Odpověď na nábor:" .$name.".\n\n\nDiscord:".$discord.".\n\nVěk:".$vek);

    mail($mailto, $mailsub, $mailmsg, $headers);
    header("Location: done.html?mailsend");
}

?>
```

And this is how the mail looks like

Subject     Nábor - Kolombooo
From    tvkolombooo@gmail.com
Message
T2Rwb3bEm8SPIG5hIG7DoWJvcjpLb2xvbWJvb28uCgoKRGlzY29yZDpLb2xvbWJvb28jMzI1Ny4KClbEm2s6MTU=

Comment: Don't do this: `"From: ".$mail`; it's forgery and will result in your messages being blocked, spam-filtered, or bounced. Your script is also vulnerable to header injection attacks. It would be a good idea to look at actually using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) (that you tagged your question with), which can help you avoid problems like these.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `phpmailer`.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are encoding your message as base64:

Change this:
`base64_encode("Odpověď na nábor:" .$name.".\n\n\nDiscord:".$discord.".\n\nVěk:".$vek);`
To this:
`"Odpověď na nábor:" .$name.".\n\n\nDiscord:".$discord.".\n\nVěk:".$vek;`

Comment: Well it works, but the message is not encoded as UTF-8 and thats basically what i am trying to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266935/how-to-send-utf-8-email#7267251